# How to print the address of the array name variable?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    int arr[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout<<arr<<'\t'<<&arr;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print the address of the variable arr which stores the address of the first element of the array, but &arr will give us the address of the first element of array again.

Comment: They simply have same value.

Comment: @Human I recommend you to examine Array Decay issue in C++.

Comment: `arr` does not store the address of the first element, it is the entire array. And an array starts exactly where its first element is.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no discrete variable that holds the formal address of the array. It literally does not exist. So there's nothing whose address can be obtained.

`arr` represents the location of the first value in the array, and this book-keeping is done entirely by your C++ compiler, when this program gets compiled. After it's compiled you're left with the program that has five `int`s, where they should be, and every reference to the `arr`, in the code itself, references this address.

If you'd like a formal pointer to the beginning of the array you will have to create one yourself:

```
int *arrp=arr;
```

Now you can `arrp`'s address.

Comment: The first paragraph does not make sense. There currently is no variable that holds the address of the array, but that is trivially added: `auto address = &arr`. `arr` itself does not represent the address of the first element, as is obvious from `sizeof(arr) != sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: *"`arr` represents the location of the first value in the array"* Only after the implicit conversion to a pointer. *"If you'd like a formal pointer to the beginning of the array"* Or, formally (:P) an *lvalue* pointer to the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print the address of the variable arr which stores the address of the first element of the array

`arr` variable doesn't store the address of the first element of the array. `arr` variable is **the array**. The address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array. (However, a pointer to the array and pointer to the first element have different types).

Comment: I want to add that when the array is converted to a pointer to its first element, the resulting pointer is computed on the fly. It's normally not stored anywhere else before that.